# How to initialize inherited class with base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an instance of this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string GetJson()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

but in some cases I need more properties in serialized json. I thought I should make a second inherited class like this:

```
public class MyInheritedClass : MyClass
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

If I'm not solving the problem in the wrong way, how can I initialize a new instance of my second class with an instance of the first one and have a json string from `GetJson()` that contains all the three properties?

Comment: I think you are right about your wrong way.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987302/deserialize-classes-which-inherit-from-superclass-with-json-net

Comment: @A.T. guide me to the write path :V

Comment: If you want more in the inherited class than your json should be calling the inherited class and not the base class.  When you call the inherited class it will call the base class constructors.

Comment: @Blendester I took the challenge please have a look on my way :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a constructor in your derived class and map the objects,

```
public class MyInheritedClass : MyClass
{
    MyInheritedClass (MyClass baseObject)
    {
        this.UserName = baseObject.UserName; // Do it similarly for rest of the properties
    }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

MyInheritedClass inheritedClassObject = new MyInheritedClass(myClassObject);
inheritedClassObject.GetJson();
```

**Updated Constructor :**

```
        MyInheritedClass (MyClass baseObject)
         {      
           //Get the list of properties available in base class
            var properties = baseObject.GetProperties();

            properties.ToList().ForEach(property =>
            {
              //Check whether that property is present in derived class
                var isPresent = this.GetType().GetProperty(property);
                if (isPresent != null && property.CanWrite)
                {
                    //If present get the value and map it
                    var value = baseObject.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(baseObject, null);
                    this.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(this, value, null);
                }
            });
         }
```

Comment: Actually this is what I want. just my problem is that I wish mapping occur automatically, so if properties of base class change, my inherited class not get outdated.

Comment: I hoped it not take that much effort, but everything has a cost.. Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to check for the presence of a base class property in the derived class? Doesn't the derived class naturally contain all properties of its base class?

Answer (score 4):

One of the options is to serialize the base class object and then deserialize it to derived class.
E.g. you can use [Json.Net serializer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

```
 var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {  //You can specify other settings or no settings at all
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore 
            };
 string jsonFromBase = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(baseObject, Formatting.Indented, jsonSerializerSettings);
 derivedClass= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DerivedClass>(jsonFromBase) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create an instance of child class that is `MyInheritedClass` and it will hold all the properties from both the classes.

When you create an instance of child class `MyInheritedClass`, runtime will call the constructor of Parent class `MyInheritedClass` first to allocate the memory for the member of parent class and then child class constructor will be invoked.

So instance of Child class will have all the properties and you are referring to the `this` while serializing the object so it should have all the properties serialized in json.

Note: Even though you are serializing the object inside the method that is declared in parent class, referring to `this` object will refer to the current instance that is instance of Child class so will hold all the properties.

Comment: Thanks. I have an object of parent class in hand, is there a way to create a child object from it or I should create a new one and assign properties one by one? this throws an exception `MyInheritedClass child = (MyClass)parent;`

Comment: You cannot assign base class object to derived class object.

Comment: So how to move values of parent to child when creating a new child object? I'm afraid if I do it manually, if parent code get changed and have more properties, my inherited class get outdated.

Answer (score 2):

No. you can't initialize the derived instance in base class object.

However you can create seprate extension method,

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string GetJson()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }

    public class MyInheritedClass : MyClass
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public static class MyClassExtension
    {
        public static MyInheritedClass ToMyInheritedClass(this MyClass obj, string email)
        {
            // You could use some mapper for identical properties. . . 
            return new MyInheritedClass()
            {
                Email = email,
                Password = obj.Password,
                Username = obj.Password
            };
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
 MyClass myClass = new MyClass { Username = "abc", Password = "123" };
 var myInheritedClass = myClass.ToMyInheritedClass("abc@mail.com");
 Console.WriteLine(myInheritedClass.GetJson());
```

output would be:

```
{"Email":"abc@mail.com","Username":"123","Password":"123"}
```